# Is there an ETag that can be sent on an `if-modified` header to see if a new video has been added to a channel or playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In the past, we've sent the channels ETag in the `if-modified` header to see if new videos have been added before trying to reprocess all the videos in the channel. However, because of an update, adding a new video is no longer considered modifying a channel and we get a `304 - Not Modified` even if new videos have been added. Is there another ETag I can use to see if a new video has been added? Any suggestions on the best way to see if new videos have been added to prevent us from over-processing the feed if nothing has been added would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is there another ETag I can use to see if a new video has been added?` - I'm not familiar with the ETag or the way you used for check if new videos has been added, but, one way can be: get the XML rss of the given YouTube channel and check the latest `published` date of the video - [YouTube example XML](https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=gcflearnfree).

Comment: Let us know if that works for you. If you need further help, I suggest you to include the code you're using. Also, consider, post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).